# Need Help sending function with parameter to a container

Tags: javascript

Hello:  I am trying to basically have a container; and then have buttons that basically send a javascript function to run in the container; and so I can have different buttons send the same function to the container with different parameters…

so - each time a button is hit the container is emptied out and the new result will show…

I found some code that does this for "text"; but when I tried to send a function with parameter it did not work…

I am starting to learn JS and not sure what it will take to do this, I am sure it can be done one way or another… here is my code:

```
<p id="id57512">How are you?</p>
<button id="b1">Answer</button>
<button id="b2">Question</button>
<button id="b3">Gman Info new</button>
<button id="b4">Run function</button>

<script>
function f1() {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue="Fine, thank      you.";}
function f2() {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue="How are you?";}
function f3() {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue="Gman needs a job.";}
function f4() {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue="gman_code1(23);";}

var gman_code1 = function(number) {
var result1 = number*2;
console.log(result1);
}

//define the behavior
document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", f1 , false);
document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", f2 , false);
document.getElementById("b3").addEventListener("click", f3 , false);
document.getElementById("b4").addEventListener("click", f4 , false);
</script>
```

1. the container is the "p" tag…
2. the first three buttons just do normal text
3. the fourth button is where I am trying to send the function with parameter
4. the f4 function is where I am trying to send the function; and it is not working…

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong that will fix this?  Or is this not doable this way and needs to be done some other way?

I am hoping someone can help with this…

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function f4() {document.getElementById("id57512").firstChild.nodeValue=gman_code1(23);
     //caling gman_code1 and assigning result to p#id57512    
    }


    var gman_code1 = function(number) {
    var result1 = number*2;
    console.log(result1);
    return result1;//add return statement
}
```

Heres the demo http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/d0ms9uw5/5/

Answer (score 0):

This will not work cross browsers, usually manipulating DOM elements is done using jQuery. Code would look something like:

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready() 
// http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
$(function() {
    //add click event
    $('#b1').click(
        function (event){
            $("#id57512").Val("Fine, thank you.");
            //or call f1();
        }  
    );
    function f1() {
        $("#id57512").Val("Fine, thank you.");
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/margusmartsepp/d0ms9uw5/6/

Comment: thanks so much Margus, I got vikrants code to work, but I will see if I can get yours to work as well...

Comment: You need to add : "<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>" if you did not notice.